# How can I do that in bouncyCastle (get installed certificates)?

Tags: c#, x509certificate, bouncycastle

Ok, I am quite new to the crypto world of bouncyCastle, and perhaps is a mental block, I can't seem to find(/google for) the equivalent to:

```
X509Store store = 
new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
```

I think it might be the easiest and dumbest thing, but how can I access the windows installed certificates, using bouncy castle?

Or if I can't, how can i convert my `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2` 
to `Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Bouncycastle doesn't have access to Windows certificates store, that is the role of Microsoft's .NET classes. To convert between .NET certificates and their Bouncycastle equivalents look at the methods in the `Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities` class, particularly the `ToX509Certificate` and `FromX509Certificate` methods.

Comment: Awesome, mate. Thank you so very much! If i could I`d give two ups

Comment: I have a Certificate which is password protected. I got this Certificate from X509Store. When i tried to convert the keypair using DotNetUtilities.GetKeyPair(cert.PrivateKey) i am getting an error 
"Key not valid for use in specified state."

Answer (score 1):

I convert the `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2` to a `Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate` using the following method

```
public static org.bouncycastle.x509.X509Certificate 
        convertToBCX509Certificate(X509Certificate2 cert) {

    X509CertificateParser parser = 
            new X509CertificateParser(cert.Export(X509ContentType.Cert));
    return parser.ReadCertificate();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Init the Certificate:

```
Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate certificate = new Certificate...
```

Then:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store CertificateStore = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store(StoreName.CertificateAuthority, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
CertificateStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
CertificateStore.Add(new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(certificate));
CertificateStore.Close();
```

Pseudo code, as an example as I am away from my working Machine atm, however, this should work nicely.